# Scrapy - only returns yield from 1 url of list

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm crawling a website which has many countries, ex: amazon.com, .mx, .fr, .de, .es,...
(the website is not actually amazon)

I've made a url list of each base url and call parse with each one:

```
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

I also have a list of keywords that it will search ex: toshiba, apple, hp, ibm,...

In the parse function I loop through each keyword and create a build url
ex: amazon.de/search?={keyword} in the correct format, this in turn calls another callback function:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for keyword in self.keywords:
        ...(make build url with keyword)...
        yield scrapy.Request(build_url, meta={'current_page': 1}, callback=self.crawl)
```

The function crawl will get the href of each listing on the page and follow it with a callback:

```
def crawl:
    ...(finds the href of each listing)...
    for listing in listings:
        yield scrapy.Request(self.main_url + href, callback=self.followListing,meta={'data':data})
```

data is a scrapy item which I fill in `followListing()` with the data I'm interested in.
ex: name, description, price, image_urls, etc... This final callback ends with a `yield data` which I would like to save in an output file.

```
def followListing(self, response):
    ...(fills up data item)...
    yield data
```

when I run my crawler:

```
scrapy crawl my_crawler -o output.json
```

The output.json file only contains the listings from one of the url's (ex: amazon.mx), each time I run it it can contain the listings of a different url but only from one of them.

I suppose that as soon as one finishes it saves to the output file so the first one finished is the only one saved. Is this the case? How can I get the output with the yield from all of them or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: please create a [mre].

Comment: Hi Alexander, ok, I just did a working example for you. You're going to have to add the spider to a scrapy project. 
https://sharemycode.fr/nyg you'll see in the output file only listings for one of the 4 urls in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your spider, including the way you are constructing the urls and sending initial requests. Plus there are quite a few areas that have a lot of room for improvement, not least of which is the fact that you are using beautiful soup instead of the built in scrapy selectors.

1. The Data class is not a proper scrapy item class, and the way you use it in your spider kind of makes it irrelevant too since you end up yielding all the information as a dictionary anyway. You should either change it like in the example below or remove it entirely.

```
class Data(scrapy.Item):
    url: str = scrapy.Field()
    description: str = scrapy.Field()
    user: str = scrapy.Field()
    images: list = scrapy.Field()
```

2. probably the main issue is in how you are generating the initial requests. In your example you have a list of base urls that yield a request for each of them, then in your parse callback you construct the path and parameters from other static attributes.  Since you can easily construct the url without dispatching the base address, it makes all of those initial requests useless. Instead what you should do you convert the parse method into a regular method that constructs each of the full urls and feeds them back to the `start_requests` method to yield as the initial requests.

```
class Example(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example'
    search = '/search?category=&keyword='
    keywords = ['terrains', 'maison', 'house', 'land']
    main_url = ''
    search_term = ''

    def gen_requests(self, url):
        for keyword in self.keywords:
            build_url = url + self.search
            kws = keyword.split(' ')
            if (len(kws)>1):
                for (i, val) in enumerate(kws):
                    if (i == 0):
                        build_url += val
                    else:
                        build_url += f'+{val}'
            else:
                build_url += kws[0]
            yield scrapy.Request(build_url, callback=self.parse)

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['https://ci.coinafrique.com', 'https://sn.coinafrique.com', 'https://tg.coinafrique.com', 'https://bj.coinafrique.com']
        for url in urls:
            for request in self.gen_requests(url):
                yield request
```

3. Beautiful soup is slow, especially when using the 'html.parser' backend, it is also much more verbose.  I suggest using the built in scrapy xpath and css selectors to parse the html and extract the information.

```
    def parse(self, response):
        for listing in response.css('div.col.s6.m4'):
            href = listing.xpath('.//p[@class="ad__card-description"]/a/@href').get()
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(href), callback=self.followListing)

    def followListing(self, response):
        url = response.url
        description = response.xpath('//div[@class="ad__info__box ad__info__box-descriptions"]//text()').getall()[1]
        profile = response.css('div.profile-card__content')
        user = profile.xpath('.//p[@class="username"]//text()').get()
        images = []
        for image in response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"slide-clickable")]/@style').re(r'url\((.*)\)'):
            images.append(image)
        yield Data(
            url=url,
            description=description,
            user = user,
            images = images
        )
```

Altogether this example does not produce the issue you described in your question.  It successfully crawls each of the results from the initial base urls.

```
import scrapy


class Data(scrapy.Item):
    url: str = scrapy.Field()
    description: str = scrapy.Field()
    user: str = scrapy.Field()
    images: list = scrapy.Field()

class Example(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example'
    search = '/search?category=&keyword='
    keywords = ['terrains', 'maison', 'house', 'land']
    main_url = ''
    search_term = ''

    def gen_requests(self, url):
        for keyword in self.keywords:
            build_url = url + self.search
            kws = keyword.split(' ')
            if (len(kws)>1):
                for (i, val) in enumerate(kws):
                    if (i == 0):
                        build_url += val
                    else:
                        build_url += f'+{val}'
            else:
                build_url += kws[0]
            yield scrapy.Request(build_url, callback=self.parse)

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['https://ci.coinafrique.com', 'https://sn.coinafrique.com', 'https://tg.coinafrique.com', 'https://bj.coinafrique.com']
        for url in urls:
            for request in self.gen_requests(url):
                yield request

    def parse(self, response):
        for listing in response.css('div.col.s6.m4'):
            href = listing.xpath('.//p[@class="ad__card-description"]/a/@href').get()
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(href), callback=self.followListing)

    def followListing(self, response):
        url = response.url
        description = response.xpath('//div[@class="ad__info__box ad__info__box-descriptions"]//text()').getall()[1]
        profile = response.css('div.profile-card__content')
        user = profile.xpath('.//p[@class="username"]//text()').get()
        images = []
        for image in response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"slide-clickable")]/@style').re(r'url\((.*)\)'):
            images.append(image)
        yield Data(
            url=url,
            description=description,
            user = user,
            images = images
        )
```

Comment: The Data class in the example is just a reduced version made specifically for the example, but shouldn't really change the output.  My example as is returns the listings of each base url for you? On my end it only outputs the listings for one of the 4 and that seems to change randomly every time I run it. I also didn't know that there was a big performance difference between bs4 selectors and scrapy selectors. Thanks for the tips overall, I will test it right away.

Comment: I will mark it as correct, your version works perfectly, thanks for that, I'll update my code to use that. Also I have a loop to crawl multiple pages, I'm adding it to my post. If you have any recommendations on improving it I appreciate it a lot. 
On a separate note I still don't understand why the original version I wrote doesn't output the listings from each of the urls in start_urls.

Comment: @DrSocket  To be honest I am not sure why your example doesn't work either but I am almost certain it has something to do with #2 in my answer.

Comment: @DrSocket  I also don't really understand what you are doing with the data in the for loop?  It looks like you extract the information and then never do anything with it. and just move on the the next page.  I suggest opening a new question with that code and a detailed explanation on what the problem is.

Comment: I'm updating the code and removed it, I was passing the data obj to the request via meta={'data': data} and using it in the callback function followListing. Not necessary with your solution since followListing has all the variables and yields the Data object, in my original solution some of the data variables were filled before following the listing.

Comment: I added my the updated code with the next_page logic to my original question, with max_page = 2, I get only output from page 2. I think it must be the same reason from the original problem.

Comment: @DrSocket  Please open a new question with the new issue.

Comment: done! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75654114/scrapy-recursive-function-as-callback-for-pagination